# Can I bring two new unopened iPhone (12mini and 13pro) to India? I am leaving 2 unused phones in my suitcase will that be an issue too?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india

I'm a student in New Zealand.
I am using iPhone 7 now, soon I'll be changing to 13pro for my personal use, and I will throw the 7 in my suitcase. I am getting two new phones for my brothers too. So will it cause me trouble to carry the following

1. Carry on - 2 unopened/opened phones
2. Checked-in baggage suitcase- 2 old phones, Old iPhone 7, and an old broken Samsung

This is my plan for now. Should I open those two new phones? Or should I get them packed fresh?
Will there be any issue leaving the unused old phones in checked-in baggage?
Kindly help; it is causing me so much anxiety.

Comment: This is a comment, as I don't know Indian law regarding duty on electronics. Like other countries, India requires duty to be paid on imported goods if their value exceeds the exempt amount. Whether the new phones are opened or not: they're still new, and you're importing them.  If you declare the phones, you won't be in trouble but you may have to pay duty. On the other hand, if you don't declare them and they search and find the phones, you risk having the phones confiscated by Customs, and you may be charged with an offense because you're required to declare what you bring into the country.

Comment: Don't check any of the phones in baggage, because they contain lithium batteries.